# Efficient way to play separate sounds upon mouseover and click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

Please keep in mind that I am pretty new to JavaScript, and I know near-enough nothing regarding it. I've [cross-posted this to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/6p16cz/i_need_help_with_sound_upon_hover/) as well.

I am in the middle of editing a website, and I want an audio file to play upon a link hover. I currently have:

```
function playclip() {
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" && 
(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7")!=-1) || 
(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 8")!=-1)) {
if (document.all)
 {
  document.all.sound.src = "../audio/hover.mp3";
 }
}

else {
{
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
audio.play();
}
}
}
```

In a file called sound-mouseover.js, in a "js" folder at the root of the website.

I then have

```
<audio>
<source src="audio/hover.mp3"></source>
<source src="audio/hover.ogg"></source>
</audio>
```

just before the ending  tag in the HTML file.

Finally, I have

```
onmouseover="playclip();"
```

during all the `<href>` tags I want the sound to be played in.

This all works fine, however...

I want this to work exactly like the "Cloned `<audio>`, one for each menu item" section on [this website](https://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/). Does anybody know how to go about this? I want to keep both mp3 and ogg files since it increases the range of web browser support.

I also want a different sound file (still using both '.ogg' and '.mp3' files) to play upon clicking said links.

The website I'm editing can be seen [here](https://coffeetipm8.github.io/). I want one sound file to play when hovering over the Discord/Twitter links, and a different sound to play when actually clicking them.

Answer (score 1):

Just detect the type that the browser can play and initialize a new `Audio` node with the `src` set to the audio file location of that supported type.

Then on `mouseover`, just play the audio node of the hovered item.

Here's a working example of what you're trying to accomplish:

```
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu')

var items = {
  one: {
    ogg: 'https://instaud.io/17my/download',
    mp3: 'https://instaud.io/17mz/download'
  },
  two: {
    ogg: 'https://instaud.io/17mA/download',
    mp3: 'https://instaud.io/17mB/download'
  }
}

var canPlay = (new Audio()).canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? 'mp3' : 'ogg'
var type = canPlay === 'mp3' ? 'audio/mpeg' : 'audio/ogg'

for (var id in items) {
  var item = items[id]
  var audio = new Audio()
  audio.type = type
  audio.src = item[canPlay]
  item.audio = audio
}

menu.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  var target = event.target
  var id = target.dataset.id
  if (id) {
    items[id].audio.play()
  }
})
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/18dy5x6q/2/**

EDIT: Missed the part about playing different sound on clicking.

Here's an example:

```
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu')

var sounds = {
  hover: {
    ogg: 'https://instaud.io/17my/download',
    mp3: 'https://instaud.io/17mz/download'
  },
  click: {
    ogg: 'https://instaud.io/17mA/download',
    mp3: 'https://instaud.io/17mB/download'
  }
}

var canPlay = (new Audio()).canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? 'mp3' : 'ogg'
var type = canPlay === 'mp3' ? 'audio/mpeg' : 'audio/ogg'

for (var k in sounds) {
  var item = sounds[k]
  var audio = new Audio()
  audio.type = type
  audio.src = item[canPlay]
  item.audio = audio
}

menu.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  var target = event.target
  if (target.nodeName === 'LI') {
    sounds.hover.audio.play()
  }
})

menu.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var target = event.target
  if (target.nodeName === 'LI') {
    sounds.click.audio.play()
  }
})
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ckd0o5of/1/**

Comment: I also want it to play a different sound file when clicking after hovering. How would I go about this? (I literally know nothing about javascript. Sorry.)

Comment: Although your method is exactly what I'm looking for, it doesn't seem to work on images. The links I have are images (they change to different files upon hover). Can you explain to me how I go about this?